# RepositorySystemSession Null in Maven 3 Plugin Unit Test

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-3, sonatype

I am attempting to write a unit test for a Maven 3 Plugin with a dependency on Aether using the Maven Plugin Testing Harness.  When executing my tests though the **RepositorySystemSession** is null and after an extensive search I can not figure out how to inject a session into the unit tests plugin harness.

I am using Maven 3.0.3 core APIs, Maven Plugin Test Harness 2.0 and Aether 1.12.  I have tried other various combinations but appear to be missing a critical component somewhere along the line.

The code base for the example can be found here: http://www.sonatype.com/people/2011/01/how-to-use-aether-in-maven-plugins/.

The documentation for the plugin harness can be found here: http://maven.apache.org/plugin-testing/maven-plugin-testing-harness/getting-started/index.html.

My example code can be seen here:

[MyAetherMojo](https://gist.github.com/2871378)

[MyAetherMojoTest](https://gist.github.com/2871383)

Any ideas on how to get the RepositorySystemSession injected into the container for the unit test?

TIA,
Scott ES

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plugin testing harness does not support Aether testing.  You have to use the Maven Invoker Plugin as demonstrated in the How To Use Aether in Maven Plugins demo code.